# How do I locate an element that is a grandchild of another element by its text with watir-webdriver?

Tags: html, html-lists, watir-webdriver

I have some HTML like this:

```
<ul id="directory">
    <li><a id="first" href="/first">first</a></li>
    <li><a id="second" href="/second">second</a></li></ul>
```

I want to locate the link with id "second" based on its text and relationship to the ul with id "directory" and click on it using watir-webdriver.

It seems like should simply be able to say:

```
browser.ul(:id => 'directory').li.a(:text => 'second')
```

but this does not exist.

After researching, I thought maybe I should be doing it like this:

```
browser.ul(:id => 'directory').lis.a(:text => 'second')
```

but `LICollection` doesn't even have an `a` method.  I think maybe I should be doing something with `each` but I have no idea what it would be.

Is there a good way I can identify this element, without resorting to a CSS or XPath selector, using these criteria:

1. It is an anchor.
2. It has the text 'second'.
3. It is the child of an li element, which is the child of a ul element, which has the ID "directory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
browser.ul(:id => 'directory').a(:text => 'second')
```

In Watir-Webdriver, you do not need to specify the li element to get access to the link. As well, assuming a reasonably formed HTML page, any link in the ul element will be in the li element (ie I believe that the only allowed direct children of ul elements is li elements).

Comment: This solves my immediate problem, but what if the intervening elements were important?

Comment: Assuming that the intervening elements had no unique attributes, my gut answer would be to say, you should use xpath or css selectors. There would be ways to not, but each seems inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

browser.ul(:id => 'directory').a(:id => 'second')

Let me know is the above statement is working or not.